# iOS textarea stops working after scroll

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I've got a strange problem.

For some reason when I tap into my textarea and then start to scroll, then want to type into the textarea it does not work.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

**Edit**

This only happens when the keyboard is up

**Edit**

Textarea is inside an absolute positioned div

Comment: Do you think you could include an example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

After scrolling ends  try this

```
if (!yourTextArea canBecomeFirstResponder)
     yourTextArea.enabled=YES;
    [yourTextArea becomeFirstResponder];
```